# How to unit test code that uses AutoMapper ProjectTo?

Tags: unit-testing, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper for mapping Entity Framework entities to business entities. Business logic classes take `IMappingEngine` as dependency through their constructors. Then it is used in methods like this:

```
public int DoSomething()
{
    var users = _dbContext.Users.ProjectTo<UserBLL>(null, _mappingEngine);

    // ...
    // some users' processing and business logic that should be tested
    // ...

    return result;
}
```

Everything works perfect. The problem is unit tests. I figured from `ProjectTo` implementation that I need to stub `IMappingEngine.CreateMapExpression` method. But it seems overcomplicated. Is there any easier solution? Of course, it's possible to just use AutoMapper's implementation by configuring mapping in test setup method, and then passing `Mapper.Engine` to SUT, but it smells like integration test, not unit.

Comment: What's the reason behind doing these tests? You are trying to unit-test a popular 3-rd party library, which is quite trusted and already should have tests related to this. Are you sure you really need this?

Comment: The method in question is the simplest example of how I use AutoMapper for projections. Other methods have some business logic after projection, and unit tests should test that logic, not projection itself. May be I should update the question to clarify it?

Comment: Yes, you should add that information. Based on what you told, I believe instead of this you want to wrap your Projection implementation in some interface and use it like this: `return _projectionMapper.Project<User, UserBLL>(users);`. Wrapping 3rd party libraries is a good and testable practice.

Comment: *Business logic classes take IMappingEngine as dependency* To me that's not the way to go. BL objects shouldn't know anything about mapping, only about business logic. The mapper should be a separate layer between DAL and BLL. Think of it, maybe some mappings become too complicated for AutoMapper. A mapping layer gives you all freedom to implement these mappings differently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ProjectTo is just a way of generating a Select LINQ projection. You wouldn't stub out a call to Select, so you wouldn't stub out AutoMapper.

Just use AutoMapper directly in your unit tests. I don't see it any different than using other core framework assemblies or something like JSON.Net.

A separate question is the EF dependency. If you want this test to be a unit test, you'd need to mock out DbContext. But that route has extremely dubious value, a mocked out DbContext has much different runtime behavior than the real one, so much so I wouldn't trust it.